# Variable escape in bat

Tags: variables, batch-file, escaping

I have a bat file,just like it:

```
if "%HOME_PATH:nodejs=%"=="%HOME_PATH%" (
```

when my `HOME_PATH` include `"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR"`, `()` or some other character is not Allowed here!

How can I do it?

Comment: I just want to know string a has inclued string b?

Comment: improved the code style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delayed expansion.
Delayed expansion has never problems with contents

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "!HOME_PATH:nodejs=!"=="!HOME_PATH!" (
```